# OnOpenExcelWorksheet Event To Trigger When Worksheet Opens?

Tags: events, vba

How can I run code when a Worksheet opens? (The code that I want to run is contained in the opening worksheet)

Comment: Did you mean Workbook? -- Because in Excel, you "open" Workbooks. -- Some guidance for the wayward Google searcher: The accepted answer applies to switching between sheets (the tabs in your workbook). -- See the answer below that if you want to know how to run a macro when your workbook is opened.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put certain code in the Worksheet_Activate() function which will run when the sheet is selected.  Additionally, use the Worksheet_Deactivate() to run code when you leave the wokrsheet and go to another one.  These functions go in the worksheet object code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox ("Hi")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    MsgBox ("Bye")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure how to get code to run when a work*sheet* opens, but you can get it to run when a work*book* opens.

In the VBA editor, open the Microsoft Excel Object called "ThisWorkbook."  At the top of the editor window, you should see two drop-down boxes: (General) and (Declarations).  Change the (General) combo box to be "Workbook."

This will give you method called `Workbook_Open()`.  Code placed in this method will execute when you open the Excel Workbook.

---

Furthermore, you have more events at your disposable, available in the (Declarations) section when you have Workbook selected, such as `SheetActivate` and `SheetChanged`, among others.  I haven't used those methods, but they may be something to try if you need events related to individual worksheets and not just the entire workbook.

Comment: Hi, when I do that, the change from' general' to 'workbook', under Excel for MacOS I get an error notification that it is not supported. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found to autorun while opening with Worksheet code only -without Workbook code - is with the Calculate event triggered by i.e. a formula =Now().

This can be relevant if copying the sheet to a new workbook should be allowed and the VBA code to run there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use static variables to run code only once in the Worksheet.Activate function like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Static Loaded as Variant

    If Loaded <> True then
        MsgBox ("Hi")
        Loaded = True
    End If

End Sub
```